# Is it possible to retrieve response from build step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Lets assume a scenario where Job A calls Job B:

```
...
...
...

crID = build (job: "Open Change Request", wait: true, parameters: [
  string(name: "assignedTo", value: "${BUILD_USER_EMAIL}"),
  string(name: "crType", value: "Upgrade worker nodes"),
  string(name: "environment", value: "${region}")]).result
```

The above code is flawed, as `result` will return `FAILURE`, `SUCCESS`, etc...
What I require is to actually retrieve the value that Job B generates.

Is this at all possible, to retrieve the response of the job that ran as part of a `build` step?

Possibilities:

- Read log from the other job?
- Global properties?

Comment: did you check the copy artifact https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin ?

Comment: It's not an artifact, though. Job B will run some code and get back a value, and ID of a ticket. I need to get that ticket back to Job A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing so by reading the build log.

In job B print the value to log:

```
echo "Change Request ID:${crID}"
```

In job A process the log text to get the printed value:

```
openCrRawData = build (job: "Open Change Request", wait: true, parameters: [
   string(name: "assignedTo", value: "${jobInitiator}"),
   string(name: "crType", value: "Upgrade worker nodes"),
   string(name: "environmentsForCR", value: "${region}")])

crIDRaw = sh (script: "echo \"${openCrRawData.rawBuild.log}\" | grep \"Change Request ID:\"", returnStdout: true).trim().split(":")
crID = crIDRaw[1]
```